# Состояние формата ввода/вывода по умолчанию

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, вывод

При копировании состояния формата  ввода, обнаружил, что по умолчанию  оно не нулевое.  Решил провести тест: обнулить и смотреть что получается:

```
//обнуление всех флагов с сохранением старых
auto old_flags = cout.flags(0);
std::cout << "number of old flags cin/cout:  "
    << std::bitset<12>(old_flags).count()
    << "\nnumber of new flags: " << cout.flags();
//восстановление старых флагов
cout.setf(old_flags);
```

Полученный результат говорит о том, что по умолчанию были установлены **два**  формата, но после обнуления поток работает с таким же успехом.

P.S. Последный вывод выдает `ноль`. Это подтверждение того, что ни один формат  не установлен.

**Вопрос:**
   Какие же форматы установлены по умолчанию и как они влияют на состояние потока?

Comment: Допускаю, что в переопределенном операторе `<<` для `bitset` выполняется та или иная установка флагов...

Comment: @Harry, тогда я обновлю вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto old_flags = cout.flags(0);
#define  fmt(x) cout << #x << ": " << (ios_base::x & old_flags) << endl
    fmt(dec);
    fmt(oct);
    fmt(hex);
    fmt(left);
    fmt(right);
    fmt(internal);
    fmt(scientific);
    fmt(fixed);
    fmt(floatfield);
    fmt(boolalpha);
    fmt(showbase);
    fmt(showpoint);
    fmt(showpos);
    fmt(skipws);
    fmt(unitbuf);
    fmt(uppercase);
}
```

Для Visual C++ 2017 дает ненулевые `dec` и `skipws`.

Для gcc, впрочем, то же самое: https://ideone.com/amWkcN

Comment: Понел,   не подумал все проверять. А после становится очевидным, что должно быть установлено десятичная система счисления и пропуск  разделителей

Comment: Я всегда говорю, что программирование - наука экспериментальная :)